# How can I insert expo module in a React-native project?

Tags: react-native, module, admob, expo

I tried to use react-native-admob but It gives me a lot of problems. So I want to install with npm the expo module to use expoadmob that I'm sure works fine. I created a project with react native and tried to use "npm install expo --save" to add the expo module, but it didn't work. Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure to understand.

You have 2 ways to create RN application `expo-cli` and `react-native-cli`.

You can't use expo for your module because you need to have a access to the native part (created with `react-native-cli`)

```
yarn add react-native-admob@next
```

AND don't forget to link the dependencies with

```
react-native link
```